# nodejs read file, write to temporary file then copy and replace the original file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am trying to read the file, then create a temporary file then copy and replace the temporary file to the original file at the end.

Is it possible to do the following?

> ```
> // read the original file then save it to temporary file
> fs.readFile(originalPath, function (err, data) {
>             var json = JSON.parse(data);
>             json.items.push("sample item");
>             fs.writeFileSync(tmpPath, JSON.stringify(json))
> })
>
> // copy the temporary file to the original file path
> fs.readFile(tmpPath, (err, contents) => {
>             var json = JSON.parse(contents);
>             fs.writeFileSync(originalPath, JSON.stringify(json));
> });
> ```

I am doing this to prevent the changes made to original file until the process has been completed.

It doesn't seem to work due the the file is not physically saved when reading it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed all that you were trying to do from that short code snippet, but it's possible that you could get into some trouble mixing asynchronous file reading and synchronous file writing like that.

If those two line ran one after the other as you have them written, the second `readFile` wouldn't see the output created by the `writeFileSync` that's above it -- the `tmpPath` file wouldn't have been written to yet.

Comment: Thanks. That's the issue I am facing. What would be the right approach to deal with this?

Comment: There are a number of ways you could go, the closest to sticking with the code you already have would be to move the second readFile into the callback of the first readFile, just after the writeFileSync.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it wrong before and it is working by moving the second readFile into the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The copy/edit/replace might be easier to reason with [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) promises that flow like normal code than with callbacks.

[`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) provides a [promise API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api):

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises
```

Then the code can flow from top to bottom by using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for any asynchronous tasks.

```
// read the original file then save it to temporary file
async function modifyFile(originalPath, tmpPath, item){
  const data = await fsp.readFile(originalPath)

  const json = JSON.parse(data)
  json.items.push(item)

  // Save it
  await fsp.writeFile(tmpPath, JSON.stringify(json))
  await fsp.renameFile(tmpPath, originalPath)
}

modifyFile('orig.json', 'orig.json.tmp', 'new item').catch(console.error)
```

Note that [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) are ES2017 and require [Node.js 7.6+](https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2016/10/v8-release-55.html) or a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).